# Bash - Looping through the content of file and perform actions on rows and columns

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, csv

The structure of the my input files are as follows:

```
<string1>   <string2>   <stringN> 
hello   nice    world  
one     three
```

**NOTE:**, the second row has a tab/null on the second column. so second column on second row is empty and not 'three'

In *bash*, I want to loop through each row and also be able to process each individual column (string[1-N])

I am able to iterate to each row:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        line=${line/$/'\t'/,}
        read -r -a columns <<< "$line"
        echo "current Row: $line" 
        echo "column[1]: '${columns[1]}'"
        #echo "column[N] '${columns[N]}'"       
done < "${1}"
```

**Expected result**:

```
current Row: hello,nice,world 
column[1]: 'nice'
current Row: one,,three
column[1]: ''
```

Basically what I do is iterate through the input file (here passed as argument), do all the "cleaning" like prevents whitespace from being trimmed, ignore backslashes an consider also the last line.
then I replace the tabs '\t' by a comma
and finally read the line into an array (columns) to be able to select a particular column.

The input file has tabs as separator value, so I tried to convert it to csv format, I am not sure if the regex I use is correct in bash, or something else is wrong because this does not return a value in the array.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, a little fix on the on translating '\t' to *commas* and you have to set also *`IFS`* to be the comma.

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        line=${line//$'\t'/,}
        IFS=',' read -r -a columns <<< "$line"
        #echo "current Row: $line" 
        echo "column[0]:'${columns[0]}' column[1]:'${columns[1]}' column[2]:'${columns[2]}'"

done < "${1}"
```

*run:*

```
$> <the_script> <the_file>
```

**Outputs**:

```
column[0]:'hello' column[1]:'nice' column[2]:'world '
column[0]:'one' column[1]:'' column[2]:'three'
```